# Disable calendar month change when user clicks on days outside current month

Tags: c#, wpf, calendar, user-controls

I'm making my own calendar control based on the regular WPF calendar. In the month view mode, when the user clicks on days that belong to the next or previous month, the calendar month changes to the corresponding month. I want to disable this behavior, but keep those days clickable (days that doesn't belong to the current month).

I tried finding the code in charge this in the calendar style but couldn't find anything.

Anyone knows how to do it?

EDIT:
I tried using DisplayDateStart and DisplayDateEnd, but then the days outside the current month become completely invisible (and unclickable), and also the prev/next month arrows become disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.calendar.displaydatestart(v=vs.95).aspx

and

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.calendar.displaydateend(v=vs.95).aspx

I can't give you an implementation example because you havent provide any code.

Comment: I tried using DisplayDateStart and DisplayDateEnd, but then the days become completely invisible (and unclickable), and also the prev/next month arrows become disabled.